# connect powerbi to postgres

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, powerbi-datasource

I need to connect power bi to a postgreSQL server.

Basically 3rd party A host an online service for us with this data source as the backend.
3rd party B connected to the data source and produced power BI reports for us from this data.

We've severed ties with 3rd party B and now need to bring the reporting in house.

3rd Party A have given me connection details that look like this:

```
Username: u123456789
Password: pdjrntyfgshwbefgs
Database: d123456789
Host: 3rdPartyA-bi-connector.bi3xflgeewli.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com
URL: postgres://u123456789:pdjrntyfgshwbefgs@3rdPartyA-bi-connector.bi3xflgeewli.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com/d123456789
```

Which powerbi connector do I use to get at this data source? Web? Postgres?

EDIT:
As per @JNevill s comment below, on the postgres connectors in PowerBi, I'm trying this:
[image]

Then this:
[image]

i.e. I'm using the "Host" as the server.

Is that right? Because I get an "PostgreSQL: Exception while reading from stream" error.
I just want to make sure I'm using the correct strings in the connector first before I start trying to eliminate other causes (i.e. firewall / timeout settings).

Cheers

Comment: That looks like the info to connect to directly to postgres, so the postgres connector would make sense.

Comment: @JNevill - can you confirm that the info in "Host" is what I should input into the "Server" box in the connector as per my edit above? Ta.

Comment: Yep. That looks like what I would attempt. Did they give you a port number or is it default postgres port of 5432? If you still aren't connecting, then you may need to get on the horn with them again and have them double check that they have their networking set up correctly to allow traffic through to the RDS. That's not an atypical problem to have since networking, especially if their AWS set up is complex, can be a pain in the rear.

Comment: @JNevill - no port number, but I'll get back in touch. 
If there was a port number, how / where do I add that to the 'Host' string? Ta

Answer (score 0):

I managed to connect to the data source and this is how I managed it by using ODBC connector instead of postgresql. Might not be appropriate for everyone.

Step 1 - Download and install the **latest** Postgresql ODBC driver from here: [enter link description here](https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/odbc/versions/msi/)

Step 2 - once installed, open PowerBI, GetData and choose the ODBC connector.

Step 3 - Select None as the data source, choose advanced and in the connection string, use this format:

Driver={PostgreSQL Unicode(x64)};Server=.rds.amazonaws.com;Port=5432;Database=;sslmode=require;

Worked for me.